# friend function in CUDA C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, cuda, nvcc, friend-function

I am working on a problem that class A and B are declared in namespace test0 and a friend function f of class A declared in namespace test1. Function f receives a reference of a class B object as the parameter. Here is an simplified example.

```
namespace test0 {
    class B;
}

namespace test1 {
    void f(test0::B& b);
}

namespace test0 {
    class A {
        friend void test1::f(test0::B& b);
    };
}
```

The code works with g++. But nvcc gives the following compilation error.

```
a.cu:11:22: error: ‘B’ has not been declared
        friend void test1::f(test0::B& b);
                    ^
a.cu:11:27: error: ‘void test1::f(int&)’ should have been declared inside ‘test1’
        friend void test1::f(test0::B& b);
                        ^
```

Could you please help me figure out what the problem is? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `friend void test1::f(B& b);`? You are in test0 namespace, so it could be confusing for compiler. Or `friend void test1::f(::test0::B& b);` to make sure the resolution goes from global namespace. Second error is likely a result of the first.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen The second error is a result of the first. `friend void test1::f(::test0::B& b);` raises the same error as the original one. `friend void test1::f(B& b);` does not work even with g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to understand that nvcc isn't a compiler, it is a *compiler driver*, and in both cases, the code is compiled with gcc and the error is a gcc generated error. If you put that code in a `.cc` extension file and compile it via nvcc, there will no be no error.

But when compiling CUDA code (in a `.cu` file in this case), there are some intermediate processing stages between your code and the final g++ pass which compiles it.  Under the hood, what is happening is that your code is being transformed by the CUDA C++ front end parser to this:

```
# 1
# 2
namespace test0 { 
# 3
    class B; 
# 4
}
# 6
namespace test1 { 
# 7
    void f(test0::B & b); 
# 8
}
# 10
namespace test0 { 
# 11
    class A { 
# 12
        friend void test1::f(B & b); 
# 13
    }; 
# 14
}
```

compare that to the original `friend void test1::f(test0::B& b);` and you can see that the namespace has been stripped out by the cudafe++ pass. I don't know *why* it has been stripped out, but that is the source of the error.

I would recommend reporting this as a bug to NVIDIA if it is a real problem in your application.

Answer (score 1):

After review by the NVIDIA development team, it appears that this may be exposing a bug in the gnu compiler.  It is true that the front-end processing by the `nvcc` toolchain creates a host code (passed to the host compiler) that drops the namespace qualification for `b`'s type, but this should be acceptable because `B` has already been declared in `test0` namespace.

It appears that this has [already been reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60611) to the gnu community.

As a supporting data point, clang++ 3.9.1 on Fedora 25 compiles the code reported in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50552060/1695960) given by @talonmies with no errors and no warnings.  On my testing up through gnu 6.4.1 on Fedora25, the gnu toolchain still throws an error.  I'm not claiming this as a proof point, merely a suggestion that the claim of a bug in gnu *might* be possibly correct.  I am not a language expert. Furthermore I don't wish to start an argument here about that; it's not the purpose of this question or answer.

The NVIDIA development team has taken the issue under review and hopes to have a fix or workaround in a future CUDA release.

In the meantime, the source-level workaround suggested is to use a dummy typedef for `B` in class `A`. i.e.:

```
class A {
    typedef B dummy_t;
    friend void test1::f(dummy_t & b);
};
```

UPDATE:

The issue should be resolved in CUDA 10.1.105 (CUDA 10.1)